# Why is my iOS app icon displaying a badge number if I didn't enable badges?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

When registering for push notifications, I'm not enabling the badge alert...

```
- (void)registerForPushNotifications {
    UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notificationTypes];
}
```

...so I don't understand why it's showing.

The only way I can figure out how to disable badges from showing on my icon is by resetting the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` value in the app delegate, but this feels a little hacky. Is there any I can simply disable the badge number from showing on my app icon?

Thanks in advance for your widsom!

Comment: Could it be from a local notification?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing your app from your devices or simulator and rebuilding it in? And please ensure that there is no other place you registered a `UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge` notification type.